# TabLayout dejo de funcionar al poner NavigationDrawer

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment

Hola tengo creado un menú horizontal en el `TabLayout` desde el que muesto los `Fragment` correspondientes de este menú, pero he puesto un `Navigation Drawer` y ha dejado de funcionar el menú del TabLayout,  ahora cuando muestro los Fragment se quedan en blanco.

¿ Como puedo volver a mostrar los Fragment del `TabLayout`  ?

Este es el código del **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private DrawerLayout drawer;
private ViewPager viewPager;
HorizontalScrollMenuView horizontal_menu;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);   

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_logo_gel);

    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    horizontal_menu = (HorizontalScrollMenuView) findViewById(R.id.horizontal_menu);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    horizontal_menu.addItem("Menu 1", R.drawable.menu1_icon,true);
    horizontal_menu.addItem("Menu 2", R.drawable.menu2_icon );
    horizontal_menu.addItem("Menu 3", R.drawable.menu3_icon );
    horizontal_menu.addItem("Menu 4", R.drawable.menu4_icon );
    horizontal_menu.addItem("Menu 5", R.drawable.menu5_icon );

    horizontal_menu.showItems();

    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            horizontal_menu.setItemSelected(position);
            currentPosition = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    });

    horizontal_menu.setOnHSMenuClickListener(new HorizontalScrollMenuView.OnHSMenuClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onHSMClick(MenuItem menuItem, int position) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull android.view.MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.lateral_1:
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace( R.id.fragment_container,
                new Menu_Lateral_1()).commit();
        break;
    case R.id.lateral_2:
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace( R.id.fragment_container,
                new Menu_Lateral_2()).commit();
        break;
    case R.id.lateral_3:
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace( R.id.fragment_container,
                new Menu_Lateral_3()).commit();
        break;
    case R.id.nav_share:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Share", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case R.id.nav_send:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Send", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
}
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}



private class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new Menu_1();
            case 1:
                return new Menu_2();
            case 2:
                return new Menu_3();
            case 3:
                return new Menu_4();
            case 4:
                return new Menu_5();

            default:
                return new Menu_5();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 6;
    }
}
}
```

Código del **activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.SoCu.CirDocu.MainActivity"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.FondoMenu"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"/>

    <com.SoCu.Docu_A.custom_views.HorizontalScrollMenuView
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:backgroundMenuColor="#0099cc"
        app:backgroundNotifications="@color/colorAccent"
        app:icon_height="30dp"
        app:icon_width="30dp"
        app:item_backgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:item_colorSelected="#ffffff"
        app:item_textColor="#ffffff" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ver_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Las imágenes de arriba muestran el menú horizontal, con el contenido en blanco, y las imágenes de abajo son el menú lateral y un enlace para mostrar el contenido de ese Fragement.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Igual aqui se vera mejor el problema.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iQQ_DmvpidA

Gracias.

Comment: Puedes agregar una imagen del problema

Comment: @David te he puesto la imagen arriba, poco se puede ver ya que cuando estas en los menús horizontales, veras que esta ese Fragment en blanco, tendría que mostrar una página web local como las que tiene las que están en el Navigation Drawe. He puesto también y pequeño video para que veas mejor lo que pasa.
Como veras también cuando visualizas un elemento del menú lateral, luego si intentas ver otro del menú horizontal, no se quita.

Comment: pero que fragment va a contener el ViewPager?

Comment: Así tengo creado el menú horizontal, y normalmente va a leer páginas web locales, igual que el menú lateral, y si puedo también abrirá documentos pdf dentro de la aplicación.y lo mismo si me sacas de ahi no se seguir :( pero todos los frsgment van abrir páginas web, lo siento estoy escribiendo desde el móvil y no se me da muy bien

Comment: @David y compañia, no sé si llegaste a ver el video, lo puse como privado y posiblemente no se visualizará, ahora lo he cambiado, por si queréis echarle un vistazo para ver mejor lo que pasa y me podéis dar alguna solución.